# Refer a different package from the godoc of a package

Tags: go, godoc

Can someone let me know if it is possible to refer a different package from `godoc` of a package? For example let's say I have a package `src/logger/`. In `src/logger/doc.go` I need to refer `src/config/`. Something like `@see` in javadoc.

Is there a recommended way?

I am on Go 1.7.

Comment: Easiest examples is to look at Go's actual documentation on https://golang.org/pkg/ and browse around until you find it.  Then click on the source file and look at the actual comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Go 1.19's enhancements to GoDoc, this is now possible with [documentation links](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/fluhus/godoc-tricks#hdr-Documentation_Links).

```golang
// Foo returns a [os.File].
func Foo() *os.File {
```

Answer (score 4):

I am not aware that this is currently possible. E.g. https://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#TempFile refers to the `os` package simply using `*os.File`. See the source code comments at https://golang.org/src/io/ioutil/tempfile.go#L40.

> and writing, and returns the resulting *os.File.